# Django imageField not validating - Why?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model:

```
class PartnerPrefs(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    theme = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    logo_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos/')
```

And my forms:

```
class PartnerPrefsForm(ModelForm):

    theme = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=THEME_CHOICE,
        widget=forms.Select(),
        initial='1',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PartnerPrefs
        exclude = ('partner',)
```

And my views:

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    prefsform = PartnerPrefsForm(request.FILES, request.POST)
    if prefsform.is_valid():
        # do stuff
```

And finally my template:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' form action='.' method='post'>  
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ prefsform.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Whenever I submit the form all field come back with `This field is required...`. If I eliminate the `ImageField` from the form, then it works fine. I cannot find what the problem is.

Comment: Arghh. turns out the order of `request.POST`, and `request.FILES` is important! Reverse them and it works. Doh!

Comment: You should answer your own question, so it's here for future reference (and doesn't show as unanswered)

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the order in which `request.POST` and `request.FILES` are passed to the from. `request.POST` must go first.